# camera activity does not return back to it's parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I'm trying to open android camera, and when I press OK the camera activity should return to the parent activity" the one that from which i started the camera activity"

but what happens now is, when I press OK, the camera activity remains on the screen and does not return back to the parent activity.

**code**:

```
    private String retrievePath() {
    int []x = imgOpHlpr.getIDs();
    String s = imgOpHlpr.getImg_Path(x.length);
    return s;       
}
```

**Code**:

```
private static final int RequestCode = 0;
OnClickListener btn_TakePictureListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        String imgPath = retrievePath();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getImageUri(imgPath));
        startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode);
    }
};
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (RequestCode == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       //String s = data.getData().toString();
       //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "picture is taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }           
}
```

Comment: What you mean by remains on the screen? can you paste your logs here.Also paste retrievePath method body

Comment: logcat and retrieve path are posted now

Comment: Same here, with a real device (Samsung Galaxy S I9000, CyanogenMod of Android 4.3): camera does not finish & return to the calling activity after taking (and saving) a picture. At the same time, the same code does work as intended on a Samsung Gio with Gingerbread.

Answer (score 2):

The emulator does not provide camera support. Refer http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14545 . So check in device.

Check

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.getExtras().get("data") != null) {
                Bitmap photo = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"), 90, 90, false);
               if(photo != null){
                   Log.d("Photo","photo not null");
}
```

Comment: emulator does not have camera, but if you call camera, it will not be forcefully closed, instead it will start the camera (we'll be seeing only black screen) and if we click capture button, it will return android logo. So even if psychicLit is using emulator, he should not suffer from any problem.

Comment: the problem is: after clicking OK, the camera activity doesnt return to its parent activity

Comment: no, but i have implemented another activity that opens the camera and it returns normally to its parent...but in this posted case, it does not

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode); returns the image. Put a log and check for data in intent. See updated answer.

Comment: but i think u gorgot to check if the request code of the camera activity is equal to the request code defined in the parent activity.